# AWS Cloudfront and browser cache settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi so I have AWS Cloudront running on my site. I also enabled browser caching through .htaccess file.

Soon after I enabled browser caching my Cloudfront hits went very low and misses very high.

My htaccess has following:

```
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days" 
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 7 days" 
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 7 days" 
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 7 days" 
ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 7 days" 
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 7 days" 
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
```

Is this to be expected with browser caching and Cloudfront? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your specific `.htaccess` configuration - this could very well cause what you've seen.

### Cloudfront Behaviour

If your backend doesn't nominate any specific cache headers, then cloudfront will cache according to your cloudfront configuration - but as there are no cache headers, the browser will generally NOT cache, but will hit cloudfront on each request.  Cloudfront will record each as a HIT.

If your backend does nominate cache headers, Cloudfront will respect them  - but also will pass them onto the browser, so the browser itself may cache the object.  As such, the browser will only hit Cloudfront when the cache expires - but by that time, Cloudfront will also have expired its cache of the object - and will thus record it as a MISS.

See [Specifying How Long Objects Stay in a Cloudfront Edge Cache](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html) and [Specifying the Amount of Time that CloudFront Caches Objects for Web Distributions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationDownloadDist) for more details on how Cloudfront and the browser handle different combination of origin headers.

### .htaccess Config

Each of the [ExpiresByType](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html) directives will cause a cache header `Cache-Control: max-age=604800` to be added to each request (604800 is the number of seconds in 7 days) - which will signal to the browser that it can cache the object for that duration.

See this [Caching Tutorial](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CONTROL) for a more detailed explanation of the different headers you can use to effect caching and their impact on caches (e.g. Cloudfront) and browsers.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping out. I have the following in my htaccess file:ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 7 days"

ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"

Comment: I don't have cache headers configured

Comment: It's very hard to interpret in a comment, could you edit your question and add there?

Comment: Edited answer with a bit more info.

Comment: So in sequence which caching settings come first and which last? Cloudfront or htaccess?

Comment: Added some links to relevant cloudfront doco that may help explain.

Comment: How long does cloudfront keep cache in its location? I'm a bit confused as I've configured browser caching but no cache headers in cloudfront. I'm only seeing 10% average hits for my files so something is wrong in my configuration

Comment: Cloudfront will cache for as long as the backend tells it to - so for 7 days.  10% is probably because the _browser_ is caching the file, so cloudfront is not seeing the request at all - it's only seeing the request once the browser expires its cache - at which point cloudfront has also expired its cache.  Depends on how many users are new users vs existing users. Check the cloudfront total request count and if it went down after introducing browser caching.

Comment: Yes what about new users? 70 percent of my traffic is new users. Shouldn't cloudfront send cached files from its locations?

Comment: Sorry I'm a cloudfront newbie

Comment: One thing I noticed if i go to an image url never opened before it show cloudfront miss first time. Then if I refresh the image url the hit shows up in the headers. Is that normal?

Comment: You said: " it's only seeing the request once the browser expires its cache - at which point cloudfront has also expired its cache." How to make it so that cloudfront sends a cache file to the user's browser after browser cache expires? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah also I'm running the site on Drupal 6 so that's also a headache as I've not installed the Drupal cdn module for Cloudfront